# Magical Record : sum aggregation

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm doing an aggregation on entities and the code is :

```
 NSPredicate *betweenInterval = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date < %@)", [interval.start value], [interval.end value]];

 NSNumber * nbPoints = [OMSPointsEventEntity MR_aggregateOperation:@"sum:" onAttribute:@"nbPoints" withPredicate:betweenInterval];

 return [nbPoints intValue];
```

And NbPoints is nil, I don't know why...

Hint : attribute NbPoints on my entity is a NSNumber should it be an int ?

Comment: Do you need [interval.start value]? I thought dates could just be passed in...another thing to check to make sure your predicate without the aggregation returns data...you may be filtering out everything without knowing it.

Comment: If I do MR_findall with this predicate + [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.nbPoints"]; I have the sum I was looking for. [interval.start value] is my own class and it return a NSDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about MR, but in standard Cord Data the aggregate functions have to be preceded by `@`. Maybe you should look this up in the MR documentation.

```
...MR_aggregateOperation:@"@sum"... // ???
```

If you can get an array of all the `PointsEvent` entities, you could calculate it yourself after the fetch:

```
NSNumber *sum = [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.nbPoints"];
```

As for the attribute data type, your setup seems correct: `int32` or similar or `float` in the Core Data model, `NSNumber` in your `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Comment: I did not find any documentation on this, here a few link I found (code of the function : https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject%2BMagicalAggregation.m, the official github page : https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)

Comment: Well, congratulations on your decision to use an undocumented framework. Did you try the second solution?